# ffempeg discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want to play local files in my discord voice channel, right now it joins the voice channel but it does not play anything. This is the code:

```py
if message.content.startswith('$Hest'):
    where = message.content.split(" ")[1]
    channel = get(message.guild.channels, name=where)
    voicechannel = await channel.connect()
    voicechannel.play(discord.FFempegPCMAudio(executable='D:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffplay.exe', source='D:/ffmpeg/Horse.mp3'))
```

And this is my output when I try to do it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Apanda\CustomMultiPyBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:/Apanda/CustomMultiPyBot/main.py", line 41, in on_message
    voicechannel.play(discord.FFempegPCMAudio(executable='D:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffplay.exe', source='D:/ffmpeg/Horse.mp3'))
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'FFempegPCMAudio'
```

Comment: Just a note: I would recommend using the [`discord.ext.commands` framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html) rather than using `message.content.startswith()`, as it is generally better practice.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is just that you are trying to use `discord.FFempegPCMAudio` when the class is actually [`discord.FFmpegPCMAudio`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#ffmpegaudio).

So to correct your code:

```py
if message.content.startswith('$Hest'):
    where = message.content.split(" ")[1]
    channel = get(message.guild.channels, name=where)
    voicechannel = await channel.connect()
    voicechannel.play(
        discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
            'D:/ffmpeg/Horse.mp3',
            executable='D:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffplay.exe' 
        )
    )
```

And if you wanted to restructure this to use the [`discord.ext.commands` framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html), your code would look something like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.command(name="Hest")
async def hest(ctx, where):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=where)
    voicechannel = await channel.connect()
    voicechannel.play(
        discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
            'D:/ffmpeg/Horse.mp3',
            executable='D:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffplay.exe' 
        )
    )

bot.run("<token>")
```

Comment: Wow thank you, i really stared me blind on this one, thank you so much!